# Как сделать так, что бы коллайдер не переворачивался?

Tags: unity3d

Вот у нас есть объект, другие не должны через него проходить, желательно что бы на него гравитация действовала, но при столкновении с другими объектами он не должен переворачиваться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы используете Rigidbody то в одной из вкладок внутри этого компонента есть "Freeze rotation", дальше вы можете выбрать по какой оси не должен поворачиваться объект.